# Boost error: ‘f’ cannot be used as a function

Tags: ros-melodic, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered a really strange error. I am writing a really simple code. Mostly still empty and just learning how to write node in C++. My code consist of 3 files.

RoverMove.cpp

```
#include "rover_move/rover_move.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "RoverMove");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Subscriber goal_sub;
   ros::Publisher vel_pub;

   goal_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("goal", 1, "goal_call_back");
   vel_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
   ros::spin();
   return 0;
}
```

rover_move.h

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include"geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

#ifndef ROVER_MOVE_H
#define ROVER_MOVE_H


void goal_call_back(geometry_msgs::Twist goal);


#endif /* ROVER_MOVE_H */
```

RoverMoveLib.cpp

```
#include "rover_move/rover_move.h"

void goal_call_back(geometry_msgs::Twist goal){
// still empty 
}
```

I have input necessary config in CMake file and I got this error:

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me why this happened? I just want to try a simple code. Publishing and subscribng to Twist type message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336908/boost-error:-%E2%80%98f%E2%80%99-cannot-be-used-as-a-function/) by [mrrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/48787/mrrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2019-11-06**:
It would help if you edit your question and add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` file. Please copy and paste that file and any terminal output into code blocks, that makes it easier to read, search, and copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One problem is that when you declare your subscriber you are putting the callback function in double quotes. Try to change from

```
goal_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("goal", 1, "goal_call_back");
```

to

```
goal_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("goal", 1, goal_call_back);
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2019-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/48787/mrrius/) on 2019-11-06**:
this works! thanks. I made a mistake quoting the function name.